# Submitting form with links and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Submitting a form using a link powered by jQuery is what I am curious about. Do I just bind a click event to the link in the live() event for eg and use a submit() added to the click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I believe this answer's your question. Also, included one with support for validation, cause most form data needs to be validated. Hope this answers your question.

```
// Not Validation
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $("#frmToSubmit").submit(); 
});

// With Validation
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    // Will only submit it validate() returns true
    if( validate() ) $("#frmToSubmit").submit();
});
```

Comment: @Eagletrophy - you could be courteous and vote the answer up, and accept it if it did solve your problem as you've indicated (not whining or scolding, just sayin'). :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr.roydukkey

The above code doesn't work for me but after few changes it works fine. Here is the code that works fine on my case:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() 
{
    if($("#frmToSubmit").valid())
    {
        $("#frmToSubmit").submit();

         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

});
```